# JQUERY .get call using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, get

I'm writing JQUERY and Javascript to get content from SharePoint lists. I have a working solution that looks like the following:

```
var $countcontainer = $("#mycountcontainer");

$SP().list("My List").get({
fields: "Consultant",
view: "Completed",
where: "Author = '[Me]'"
},function getData(row) {
$countcontainer.empty().append(row.length);
});
```

This is using the sharepoint plus api and works pretty well. The problem that I'm running into is that I have a lot of lists and I want to get a count from all of my lists. My idea was to add all of the fields and views into arrays and change the code to something like this:

```
var forms = ["\"My List1\"", "\"My List2\"", "\"My List3\""];
var views = ["\"Completed\"", "\"In Progress\"", "\"Incomplete\""];
var totalcount;

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++){

 $SP().list(forms[i]).get({
    fields: "Consultant",
    view: views[i],
    where: "Author = '[me]'"
    },function getData(row) {
    totalcount += row.length;
  });

}
```

This works if I put an actual name in quotes for list and view:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++){

 $SP().list("My List").get({
    fields: "Consultant",
    view: "Completed",
    where: "Author = '[me]'"
    },function getData(row) {
    totalcount += row.length;
    alert(totalcount);

  });

}
```

For whatever reason using the array or JavaScript variables fails and gives the error:

```
Expected identifier, string or number
```

My assumption is that the array is an object and the get call is expecting a string. I have tried the following to change the variables to a string:

```
.toString()
String(""\form1\"")
forms[i]+""
```

Comment: The line `where: "Author = "'[me]'",` has a syntax error. Why is there a " mark right before `'[me]'`? Why is there a comma after `'[me]'"`?

Comment: Sorry, I copied it over incorrectly. You're right, it should be just '[Me]'" and no comma

Comment: Can you add the code that works with the hard-coded name in quotes for list and view?

Comment: Definitely, It has been added!

Comment: I'm confused. It works when you use "My List" but in the broken example you're using values like `"\"form1\""`, not "My List". Likewise with "Completed" rather than `"\"view1\""`. Shouldn't the code be something more like `var forms = ["My List", "My List 2", "My List 3"];`? Sorry if I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: You are correct, I'll make the changes quick so that they're less confusing examples. I just didn't want to use my real names as it is going to be used in a production ready application

Comment: I'm still unclear on why you're escaping quotation marks in the broken example. The working one calls `$SP().list("My List")` whereas the broken one effectively uses `$SP().list("\"My List\"")`

Comment: I believe the array stores "My List1" as My List1, but the call requires a string

Comment: No, that isn't how it works. If your array is just `var forms = ["My List", "My List 2", "My List 3"];` then `forms[0]` will pass a string with the value `My List`. `"My List"` also passes a string with the value `My List`. Take out the escaping and see if the error persists.

Comment: In other words, `var someString = "hello"; someFn(someString);`is completely equivalent to `someFn("hello");`

Comment: Oh no way...It works! Thank you!! I swear I tried this first, I must have had a syntax error before somewhere...

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.